# HiDPI support for Videos Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, video, display-resolution

My `Ubuntu GNOME 14.0.4.5 LTS` has an issue with playing videos. `vlc`, `smplayer`, `gnome-mplayer` struggle to "stretch" videos to full-screen size. That is, regardless of whether the application is in windowed mode, or full-screen, the video size remains the same. My videos look like this:

[image: Video_Playback]

I have a Dell 7559, that has a 4K Display, and probably the cause of small videos(regardless of their resolution).

Has anyone encountered this? Is there a fix?

Comment: I don't know about your particular issue, but Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS will likely have better support for HiDPI. See also http://askubuntu.com/a/781707/1579

Comment: (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ NO WAY! I tried the last answer on the page and it worked. I am so shocked that it did. I am a little afraid of upgrading to `16.04`, but thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know why it works? I am curious if you do know.