# Saved videos won't play in 16.04 Gnome VLC player

Tags: vlc

I have a Pentium 4 Gateway desktop PC. Online videos on Youtube & FB play fine but my saved videos won't play. When I click a file in file manager, the VLC player opens and gives a short 1 sec. of sound and then shuts down, there is no video and player says the video has 0B although the full size displays in properties. I've run the fixes in related threads but did not work for me. snap VLC could not be found and classic VLC is not installed even after I ran the remove/install commands. (Now terminal won't open after logging my pw.) If I open the VLC player I can't find files external to Ubuntu proper, same with Gnome player.

Comment: I just found that when right clicking a video and opening in menu, it does play, but when clicking the video directly, the player opens and then shuts down quickly as stated. Also I'm using LXDE interface.

Comment: Found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/775537/ubuntu-16-04-gnome-issues-with-videos